# Running Browser as terminal process

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, terminal, instance

I am trying to do some high scale testing with my nodejs server so I want to find out how its possible to run the chrome browser on the terminal, similar to how nodejs runs the server.

I want to have a few hundred on a single machine which is why I want to avoid running the actually browser tab instances. It also needs to specifically be google chrome.

Right now Im trying to figure out how this is possible, even if it's just somehow running the messaging javascript from the terminal.

Can someone please point me to the right direction :]

Comment: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/), or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)?  I think they may be just what you're looking for.  Phantom is a headless browser that can browse webpages for you (useful for testing, taking screenshots, and taking actions on pages for you).  CasperJS can help you out with that, as well, and Request allows you to make http requests from your server, rather than client.  If you need to search/ traverse the page your server gets back, you can also use [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cheerio), which is pretty much jQuery for your server.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you! I'll look into them, they seem to be what I need :]

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it!  If you need any help using them, I think the docs are pretty alright, and there are some really good youtube videos that show how to use them.